# Shabbos Using rotating bezel on a watch

Tags: halacha, shabbat

One may not measure on Shabbos.
Measuring time is also not allowed.
May one use a watch that has a [rotating bezel](https://watchranker.com/rotating-watch-bezels/), to time?

Comment: Source that measuring time is prohibited?

Comment: @Shalom שו"ע או"ח שח נא. מ"ב